# asp:to add web control in table cell of table control (web control ).

Tags: asp.net, insert, controls

I have inserted a table web control in a panel. In that table's cells I want to insert other user control like label, panel. I am not able to do that. Is there any difference in normal table for layout and table web control. If it is, then how can I insert simple table in a panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide us with a little more information.

I don't see any problems in what you are doing, can you show an example? Is it from code behind or in the aspx code?

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnl_something">
  <table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl_inside" />
         </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

I haven't tested that code, just wrote here.
If you are adding it from code behind, you should build the table first and in the Controls of the td add the label.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

actually i was using asp:table instead of html:table .and in asp:table i was not able add any control.but now problem is solved.thanks